# Locating Script tags on a Page

Tags: python, web-scraping, xpath

I would like some help loacting a script tag on a site I'm scraping, otto.de. I can find the xpath with xpath helper but when I use it in my code, it returns none.
Below is the particular script tag with all the info I need

```
<script id="product_data_json" type="application/ld+json">{"@context": "https://schema.org/", "@type": "Product", "gtin13": "4061519667180", "sku": "27443719", "name": "SOCCX Rundhalspullover mit längerer Rückenpartie", "description": "Ein absoluter Wohlfühlpulli ist dieser oversized geschnittene Pullover von SOCCX. Seine angeraute Oberfläche sorgt für eine mega weiche Haptik und der Logo Print mit Glitter für einen Hauch Glamour im Alltags-Outfit. Er ist perfekt für den Moment – schnell mal etwas gemütliches Überziehen!", "image": ["https://i.otto.de/i/otto/4f835f0b-ed8c-5159-a56c-a22acd7980fb/soccx-rundhalspullover-mit-laengerer-rueckenpartie.jpg?$formatz$", "https://i.otto.de/i/otto/733b0bf0-3e1e-5a45-931e-16950bca7653/soccx-rundhalspullover-mit-laengerer-rueckenpartie.jpg?$formatz$"], "aggregateRating": {"@type": "AggregateRating", "ratingValue": "4", "reviewCount": "3"}, "offers": {"@type": "Offer", "url": "https://www.otto.de/p/soccx-rundhalspullover-mit-laengerer-rueckenpartie-1759049837/", "priceCurrency": "EUR", "price": "39.95", "itemCondition": "http://schema.org/NewCondition"}, "brand": {"@type": "Brand", "name": "SOCCX"}}</script>
```

I tried using xpath,

```
script_tag = response.xpath("//script[@id='product_data_json']/text()").extract_first()

                    if script_tag:
                        print(script_tag)
                        soup = BeautifulSoup(script_tag, 'html.parser')

                        # Parse the JSON 
                        product_data = json.loads(soup.string)

                        # Extract the image URL
                        product_url = product_data['offers']['url']
                        print("Product URL:", product_url)
                    else:
                        print("Script tag not found or JSON data missing.")
```

But this returns none.
I also tried, script_tag = response.css('script#product_data_json::text').get()
but this wasnt successful either.

Can anyone explain to me what's going on? I'm new to Scrapy, this is my first big project.

Comment: you haven't shared the url

Comment: Hi, sorry, I found out I made a rookie mistake, I was scraping the product details from the search results page but that script tag was on the product page, that's why I couldn't locate it. 
Thanks for your response.