# Inconsistent results between scrapy shell and spider. Why?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Update to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77219849/locating-script-tags-on-a-page). I figured out the xpath was indeed correct while using scrapy shell.
Below is the output,
`>>> data1 = response.xpath("//script[@id='product_data_json']/text()").extract_first()

> > > data = json.loads(data1)
> > > data['image']
> > > ['https://i.otto.de/i/otto/3bd46022-3def-5f08-b4d9-207fcfbada7b/aniston-selected-jerseykleid-mit-farbenfrohem-muster.jpg?$formatz$', 'https://i.otto.de/i/otto/c50a5766-5e83-5670-9d38-5585d6bbbdca/aniston-selected-jerseykleid-mit-farbenfrohem-muster.jpg?$formatz$', 'https://i.otto.de/i/otto/e7dbf482-4827-5e12-a60a-82cd19a936cc/aniston-selected-jerseykleid-mit-farbenfrohem-muster.jpg?$formatz$']
> > > `
> > > However, using the same xpath in my spider, I can't locate the script tag.

I tried creating a new scrapy project as I had custom settings in the old one, with the new spider I had all default settings. I was expecting to locate the script but I still couldn't.
I then added the `inspect_response(response, self)` function and behold, the script tag, and other image tags I could use to get the image are no where to be seen in the response
Why would this be the case?

Anyone ever run into a similar prolem?
What are my options here?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the original question should be updated instead of posting a new one.

Comment: Without the code It's just guessing.

Comment: I'm really sorry, guys, I had made a rookie mistake checking for the element on the product page as opposed to the search results page where I was scraping the other details.